# SSLEOFError using gevent

Tags: python, ssl, gevent

I use pywsgi in gevent,like this :

```
 http_server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5000), app, keyfile="server.key", certfile="server.crt",ssl_version= ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23 )
```

Android apps connect to my server,sometimes the error occurs,what's the reason and how to resolve it?

I try with curl and find that my server supports tlsv1.0,1.1 and 1.2,doesn't support sslv2 and 3.And Android supports tlsv1.0 since long long ago.So it seems that the problem is not the version of the ssl protocol.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ec2-user/python-env/py3env/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/ge$ent/greenlet.py",line 536, in run
result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "/home/ec2-user/python-env/py3env/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/ge$ent/baseserver.py", line 26, in _handle_and_close_when_done
return handle(*args_tuple)
File "/home/ec2-user/python-env/py3env/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/ge$ent/server.py", line 174, in wrap_socket_and_handle
ssl_socket = self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)
File "/home/ec2-user/python-env/py3env/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/ge$ent/_ssl3.py", line 642, in wrap_socket
ciphers=ciphers)
File "/home/ec2-user/python-env/py3env/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 232, in __init__
raise x
File "/home/ec2-user/python-env/py3env/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 228, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
File "/home/ec2-user/python-env/py3env/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 545, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)
Thu Mar  1 03:00:23 2018 <Greenlet at 0x7f93d0e2daf8: _handle_and_close_when_done(<bound method WSGIServer.wrap_socket_and_handle of, <bound method WSGIServer.do_close of <WSGIServer a, (<gevent._socket3.socket [closed]  object, fd=-1, )> failed with SSLEOFError
```

Comment: did u ever find a solution?